# How to get JSON data parse from Arrays of dictionary iOS

Tags: ios, json

```
list = ({
    clouds = 24;
    speed = "4.31";
    temp = {
        day = "283.84";
        eve = "283.84";
        night = "283.84";
    };
}),
```

Please can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong - I want to display list-->temp-->day value in table first I am trying to get data in an array which is terminating.
Here is my code am I doing any wrong

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataBuffer options:-1 error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",json);

NSMutableDictionary * list = [json objectForKey:@"list"];

NSMutableArray *arrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

for (NSDictionary *lists in [list allValues]) {
    [arrays addObject:[list valueForKey:@"temp"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access day then use below line,

```
NSString *day = [json valueForKeyPath:@"list.temp.day"];
```

Comment: Then you should accept the answer by clicking arrow button near by answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is an array, so if you want to do your things without changing much, you can replace:

```
NSMutableDictionary * list = [json objectForKey:@"list"];
```

With:

```
NSMutableDictionary * list = [[json objectForKey:@"list"] objectAtIndex:0];
```